# windows turns screen off the screen after video

Tags: system

I am new Ubuntu User, My question is why my screen turns-off (sleep) automatically after Any full screen video i changed the timing to 5 min it sleeps now after Any 2min videos(full screen), how can i fix this

I watch movies and series(so every time it is turns off after episode finishes)